# Scala - How to call inner class method?

Tags: scala, class, methods

I have in one scala file following class (and bellow main method):

```
class OuterClass {
  class Inner {

    def innerMethod(): Unit = {
      println("innerMethod")
    }

    class InnerMost {
      innerMethod()
    }
  }
}
```

Now want to call that class from main method:

```
  object main {
    def main (args: Array[String] ): Unit = {
          println("Main")
          val pt = new OuterClass
          ...
      }
  }
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To instantiate the nested class `Inner` and then `InnerMost`

```
val pti = new pt.Inner
val ptim = new pti.InnerMost
```